# Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT

Tags: paths, updating, tlmgr, kpsewhich

I am upgrading from TeX Live 2018 to 2019 following https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html

At step 8 I encounter a problem.

Running `sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade` in `/usr/local/texlive/2019` produces errors:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: 1: ./runme.sh: kpsewhich: not found
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

`/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux` is in the `PATH`.

```
which kpsewhich
```

produces

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich
```

Running

```
kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT
```

gives

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you executed `sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade`command as a *sudoer*. Therefore, you should add texlive PATH to `secure_path`.

1. Open sudoers paths with `sudo visudo`
2. Add `/usr/local/texlive/'year'/bin/x86_64-linux` to the `secure_path` line.

Comment: This is what I did. I'm not sure how good an idea it is to change the secure_path from default, but it works fine. Another option is to run tlmgr like `sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr update --self`