# Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them

Tags: update

I am trying to remove TexLive 2018 in order to do a fresh install of TexLive 2019 after a failure to upgrade [Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516722/cannot-find-tex-live-root-using-kpsewhich-var-value-selfautoparent)

I try the first command at [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
```

I am informed that

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aglfn asymptote-doc biber chktex dvidvi fonts-adf-accanthis fonts-adf-berenis fonts-adf-gillius fonts-adf-universalis fonts-arphic-bkai00mp fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp
  fonts-arphic-gkai00mp fonts-bae ... LONG LIST OF PACKAGES
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

The list of packages is too long for a manual removal one by one.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

and the system will remove all those packages, which are no longer needed.